# Как взять цвет активного элемента elem:active на чистом js

Tags: javascript, css

Есть бегунок на диапазонном слайдере. Там со свойствами css hover и active получается все не так как хотелось бы, потому приходится заморачиваться. Нужно записать в переменную значение цвета при `elem:active`. Надо чтобы он брал это значение именно из css, а не чтобы оно задавалось в коде js. И надо выполнить это на чистом js.

```
#thumb{
    background-color: #8fcafe;
}
#thumb:active{
    background-color: #3ef;
}
var thumbElem = document.getElementById('thumb');
var thumbColor = thumbElem.style.backgroundColor;//Работает
var thumbColorActive = thumbElem.style...;//Как??
```

Comment: _thumbElem.style.backgroundColor;//Работает_ - а вообще говоря не должно. через `style` получаются только свойства из атрибута _style_ не прописанные в css файле

Comment: Он не выводит значение этого цвета в консоль, однако фактически перекрашивает обратно в него.

Comment: а вот и нет :-)

Comment: А как тогда? Заинтриговали!

Comment: Как возможно "достать" значения из css?

Comment: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, теперь как надо находит. Однако так и не получается узнать цвет псевдокласса, а не псевдоэлемента

Comment: для этого нужно чтобы этот элемент в момент проверки был активным